# JavaScript - how to change field values oninput and onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

I can't figure out how to change form field values with the `oninput` or the `onchange` method. For example, I need to make one input field to change its value as soon as another input field is being changed. So I'm trying:

```
<input type="number" id="a" value="999.99" oninput="updateInput(value)"/>
<input type="number" id="b" value=""/>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function updateInput(value) {
        document.getElementById("b").value = document.getElementById("a").value;
    });
</script>
```

It doesn't do anything. What am I doing wrong?

In another case, I need to change the value of a drop-down according to another drop-down (with an `if` clause). Since the simple script above doesn't work already, I don't even have a clue what to do about the second one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the `updateInput()` function outside of `$(document).ready()`, so that you can call it from the rest of your code, otherwise it is only scoped in there.

Secondly, the argument the function takes is never used, so I took the liberty of removing it.

Thirdly, to call this function as soon as the page is loaded, just call it inside `$(document).ready()` and you are good to go.

Here's a working example:

```js
function updateInput() {
  document.getElementById("b").value = document.getElementById("a").value;
}

$(document).ready(updateInput());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="a" value="999.99" oninput="updateInput()" />
<input type="number" id="b" value="" />
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a few issues here; the first one to sort out is where you're declaring your functions. Javascript has a concept of *scope*, which you can think of as kind of a container for declared variables. The reason your function isn't doing anything is because the definition of `updateInput` is locked away inside your jquery `$(document).ready` scope.

Once you take that definition out of the jquery wrapper, it's available to the global window scope - which is the one you're accessing in your `oninput`. I should point out that there are more flexible/useful ways to put an event listener on something, but what you have will work, if this is a simple use case.

```js
function updateInput(value) {
    document.getElementById("b").value = document.getElementById("a").value;
}
```

```html
 <input type="number" id="a" value="999.99" oninput="updateInput(value)"/>
 <input type="number" id="b" value=""/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function is undefined in the markup, because it is passed to the `ready` and scoped there. It will better to not pass the `update` function to the `ready`, but create inside it and attach that function to the `input` from code. Don't get every time the DOM elements, instead get once and use variables to keep them.

Also you have mixed `jQuery` approach with pure `Javascript` approach. I think it will be better to use one of them.

**With jQuery**

```js
$(document).ready( function() { 

   const aInput = $("#a");
   const bInput = $("#b");
   
   aInput.on('input', function () {
       bInput.val(aInput.val());
   });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="a" value="999.99"/>
<input type="number" id="b" value=""/>
```

**With pure Javascript**

```js
window.onload = function() {

   const aInput = document.getElementById("a");
   const bInput = document.getElementById("b");
   
   aInput.addEventListener('input', function() {
       bInput.value = aInput.value;
   });

};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="a" value="999.99"/>
<input type="number" id="b" value=""/>
```